# Angular 4 AOT with webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-2, angular2-aot

I am using angular 4 with webpack 2 & trying to use AOT, but its giving me this error: `10% building modules 4/5 modules 1 active ..._modules/intl/locale-data/jsonp/en.jsModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './../$$_gendir/src/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/Users/xyz/angular-upgrade/backend/myapp/angular/src'`.

This is my `webpack.config`:

```
new AotPlugin({
  tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
  entryModule: './src/app/app.module#AppModule'
}),
```

and the script I am using to make the build is: `"build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail"`

Below is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ]
}
```

Comment: These `ngfactory` files should have been auto-created during executing the build-chain - that would have been the AOT result. Maybe check back at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html and see whether your build commands and configuration are correct (search for `ngc`)

Comment: I think I don't need ngc here since I am using `@ngtools/webpack`

Answer (score 3):

AOT does not support typescript version that is above 2.0.10 now. You need to make sure that. Also, you have to change some angular modules like http, platform-browser, or core back to angular 2 -- I use version 2.4.0 --, because typescript of version 2.0.10 or below does not support them!

Comment: now using 2.4.0 version & typescript@2.0.10 still same issue, are you using webpack for AOT? & can you please paste your package.json here?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "primeng": "^2.0.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.8"

Comment: "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
 "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.3",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.10" (Devdependencies)

Answer (score 2):

First of all: you need to compile using @ngtools/webpack. 
Then your compiler options are not as Angular would expect them to be.

Please make sure you configure your setup and tsconfig.json according to the [Official Angular AOT Cookbook](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#compile-with-aot)

E.g. the module property needs to be set to:

```
"module": "es2015"
```

Also, you should tell ngc where to put generated sources by specifying

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
 "genDir": "aot",
 "skipMetadataEmit": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with `$$_gendir`

per [this post](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5294) removing `--bail` from the build command cli enabled me to see more of the error message since `$$_gendir` errors are more of a generic message caused by prior errors in the build.